# How do you make a variable have a 50 percent chance of being one value and 50 percent chance of being another?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

```
 a = document.getElementById("find").value
    if (a == 'Spark' || a == 'Fire') {
        var monster = x
        var player = y
        var damage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25)
        var damageplayer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)
        alert('Your squad succeeded the enemy has ' + (x = x - damage) + ' original territories!');
    alert ('You have' + (y = y - damageplayer) + 'original territories!'); }
```

This is my code above I'm trying to make it so that it is a 50/50 chance whether damage will = Math.Floor(math.random () *25) or = 0 . I tried multiplying a math .random by 1 then math. random by 25 and didn't work. How do you make it so 50 percent of the time it will equal 0 and the other 50 percent of the time equal math.random * 25?

Comment: You can use this: `Math.round(Math.random()*2)` which will return a 0 or 1, it's not exactly a 50% chance, but it's darn close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
var coin = function() {
    return (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1);
}

var damage = 25*coin();
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I wonder how random Math.random really is...

An alternative:

return (new Date().getMilliseconds() % 2);

Comment: Easy to test using Die Hard tests.  As good as any generator developed by Donald Knuth.  Got any proof that your way is random?  What's the period for repeats?

Comment: No, nothing particularly "random" about this from a computing perspective.  But it does adequately meet the "50/50 chance" requirement, when it is based on a user generated event.

Comment: I think it needs to be random.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `floor()` as it will always round down. Use `round()`

```
var zeroOrOne = Math.round(Math.random());
var damage = zeroOrOne * Math.floor(Math.random() * 25);
```

Or, if you are one of those "cram as much code into one line as possible" folks:

```
var damage = Math.round(Math.random()) * Math.floor(Math.random() * 25);
```

Comment: Maybe they want to round down.

Comment: This is not working. The parenthesis are missing of Math.random

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I think they want `floor()` on the `Math.floor(Math.random * 25)` part, but you can never use `floor()` to determine 50/50 part.  Well I guess you could if you did `Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)` but that would be odd I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
damage = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 0 : (Math.random() * 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
var aux = Math.random()

if (aux < 0,5){

    aux = 0

}else{

   aux = damage
}
```

Then you can use the var aux for ur porpose instead of damage

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
Math.random();
if(Math.random() >= 0.5){ \\set variable to value A }
else { \\set variable to value B }
```

Since `Math.random` will randomly select a number `0` to `1` I set the check halfway, at `0.5`.